Siri mistakenly replaces a word in my calling command
I have an iPhone 15 Pro Max and I am facing a strange problem with Siri that started happening after the 17.4 update.
The issue is that for some reason, when I use the voice command "Hey Siri, Call my brother/mother/etc" it replaces the word "my" with a Greek word "Παπά" (yes I am Greek and have set Greece as my region, but the phone's language is set to English), resulting in the "such contact not found" error...
Funny thing is that once it replies, "I couldn't find such a contact, who do you want to call?", if I repeat the same command "Call my brother", it now works correctly 
I have tried turning Siri off and on again, resetting dictation history, turning cloud sync off and changing siri language without any result...
I have also enabled captioning to see what Siri actually hears me saying and have recorded the screen. If you look closely you can see the word "my" being typed and then immediately replaced with "Παπά"..

The quality is not that great because I had to convert to gif to directly upload here...
Has anyone ever seen anything like that??? Or even better knows how to fix it?
